# SWT transformation bug

Tags: java, eclipse, graphics, rotation, swt

Today I encountered some strange behaviour of SWT's transformation code. The problem is when I try to rotate coordinate system by 45 degrees with `Transform.rotate(45f)` and then draw **outline** of a rectangle, it draws rectangle shifted.
Consider following code which draws a rotated rectangle:

```
...
m_canvas.addPaintListener(new PaintListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void paintControl(PaintEvent a_e)
        {
            GC gc = a_e.gc;
            Transform t = new Transform(gc.getDevice());
            t.rotate(m_angle);
            gc.setTransform(t);
            gc.setForeground(fgcolor);
            gc.setBackground(bgcolor);
            gc.drawRectangle(rect);
        }

    });
...
```

Also we'd have two buttons for increasing and decreasing angle by one degree. Now use that buttons to rotate rectangle from 0 to 90 degrees and see what happens around 45 degrees.
Note that if I try to use `GC.fillRectangle()` then filled rectangles rotated and drawn properly. The problem with `GC.drawRectangle()` method.

This is what it looks like:

[image]

The full code of class available [here](http://pastebin.com/izUqiYrB)
Runnable JAR (for win32) with Eclipse project source will be posted by request as I have no enough reputation.
Am I doing something wrong or there is any workaround of this problem?

Comment: That's really curious. It might be worth posting this as a bug [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Baz I've found a [bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=253670) posted in 2008.
Unfortunately there is no fix for it but there is two workarounds:

- Set the GC data state mask to `DRAW_OFFSET` after applying a transformation and before drawing:
  `gc.getGCData().state |= 1 << 14;`
- Set line attributes on the GC:
  `gc.setLineAttributes(new LineAttributes(1, SWT.CAP_FLAT, SWT.JOIN_MITER));`

I'm ended with second approach as it is considered as a platform independend solution. Note that there is no need constructor parameters be the same as above.

Comment: +1 Glad to see you found a "solution". It's sad to see that there still is no proper fix. I mean, it's basic drawing that's not working here...